# Non Recursive Merge Sort With 2 Array List

Tags: java

I'm trying non-recursive Merge Sort with 2 Arrays, But it doesn't work when given array's size is not 2^n.

It works fine when the given array's size is 2^n.

For example, given array which's size is not 2^n : `7 2 9 11 4 3 8 6 1 10`

As step is 1, sort result is :
`2 7 9 11 3 4 6 8 1 10`

And now it will sort with 4 items, 4 items, 2 items.
But it doesn't work.

so I checked the console, and it seems like, the problem is

`while(leftStart <= leftLast && rightStart <= rightLast)`.

As I catched, when checking `2 7 9 11` and `3 4 6 8` to sort, the leftStart is going to higher than leftLast, `2 < 7 (leftStart++), 2 < 9 (leftStart++)` so leftStart > leftLast, the while loop is broken ).

It should check for the others, because it could be `L1.get(leftStart) > L1.get(rightStart)`

But I don't know how to solve this problem..

Thank you for your help.

```java
    public statid void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(7);
        l.add(2);
        l.add(9);
        l.add(11);
        l.add(4);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(8);
        l.add(6);
        l.add(1);
        l.add(10);

        sort(l);
    }
    public static void sort(ArrayList l) {
        L1 = null;
        L2 = null;
        step = 1;
        L1 = l;
        L2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < L1.size(); i++)
            L2.add(null);

        int tSize = l.size();
        while(step <= l.size() ) {

            for(int i = 0; i < tSize; i += this.step*2) {

                int leftStart = i;
                int leftLast = (leftStart + this.step)-1;
                if(leftLast >= tSize-1)
                    continue;

                int rightStart = i + this.step;
                int rightLast = (rightStart + this.step)-1;

                if(rightStart >= tSize)
                    rightStart = tSize - 1;

                int idx = i;
            //  System.out.println("step : " + step + " || idx : " + idx + " || leftStart : " + leftStart + " || rightStart : " + rightStart);
            //  System.out.println("step : " + step + " || idx : " + idx + " || leftEnd : " + leftLast + " || rightEnd : " + rightLast);
            //  System.out.println();
                while(leftStart <= leftLast && rightStart <= rightLast) {


                    System.out.println("leftStart : " + leftStart + " || rightStart : " + rightStart + " || idx : " + idx);
                    Object a = L1.get(leftStart);
                    Object b = L1.get(rightStart);

                    if(comp.compare ( a, b ) < 0 ) {
                        L2.set(idx++, L1.get(leftStart++));
                        L2.set(idx, L1.get(rightStart));
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("idx :::: " + idx);
                        L2.set(idx++, L1.get(rightStart++));
                        L2.set(idx, L1.get(leftStart));
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < L1.size(); i++) {
                L1.set(i, L2.get(i));
        }
            System.out.println("============================");
            for(int j = 0; j < L1.size(); j++) {
                System.out.print(L1.get(j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n============================");

            step *= 2;
        }   
    }
```

The result:

```
1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 8 10
```

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Turing85 I did it about 2 days and I cannot find out the problem and how to solve it.
No way to get any helps, so I know, it is not good to post on stackoverflow.
But I just want to study, so I post it. if it is the problem, I will delete this post.

Comment: when n is odd, i.e. when the array cannot be split evenly in half. In that case, instead of looking at the values of T for n/2, we should use the actual lengths of the two parts. In general, left "half'' will have floor(n/2) elements and the right "half '' will have ceil(n/2). (If you haven't seen these functions already, floor(x) returns the greatest integer not more than x, and ceil(x) returns the least integer not less than x.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an array has an odd number of items, then splitting it will result in one subarray will have one more item than the other.

```
        [2,7,9,11,3,4,6,8,1,10]   
             /         \
      [2,7,9,11,3]   [4,6,8,1,10]
      /       \        /      \
   [2,7,9]  [11,3]  [4,6,8] [1,10]
   /   \             /   \    
 [2,7]  [9]        [4,6] [8]
```

Both recursive and non-recursive merge sort have the same time complexity of O(nlog(n)).
The iterative version doesn't use recursion to split the array. Rather, it uses nested loops.

Comment: How can I check the array has an odd number? I got an idea when I saw your answer, however I don't know it is good idea. Is it good way that check it like `if( array.size() == 2^n )` ?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment.
It really helped. I got a hint with you and @I'mPatrik.

<3